# How to debug DOM manipulation by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, droppable, dom-manipulation

I'm working on an website with some dynamic jQuery content.
If the user pushed a button ("show menu") on the page, an javascript function runs. Let this function call `loadMenu()`.

The `loadMenu()` function loads a menu (web conent) from server using ajax. Part of this loaded code is javascript/jquery. 2 functions of this code make some elements on the page draggable, 2 other functions make some elements on the webpage droppable. These functions are all started at $.ready-Time (if the DOM is ready).
All this works fine.

Now i added an "MenuAlwaysVisible" feature. This means: if the web-page is loading and finished (`ready`) the user doesn't need to press the button "show menu", because the javascript `loadMenu()` now fires automatically, if the page is `ready`

The problem now is, it looks like, the draggable handler are attached and worked as defined, but droppable does not work.

I'm not sure, but probably the `droppable` function runs on a time, where the DOM elements doesn't like to be droppable? Ore maybe some other jQuery codes overrides this? (but there are no other droppable elements on the page)?

So the question is: how to analyze that problem: how to debug DOM manipulation, using Windows and Firefox/Firebug or Safari, Chrome .. whatever...

Thank you!

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/javascript -- sounds like you just need to learn how to use a step-through debugger.

Comment: @mblase75 thank you for that link - i will read this right now :-)

Comment: @mblase75 the step-through debugger is strange (i think). it looks like, all the functions are fired at the time, when the browser reads the script. (stopping at my breakpoints at "script-parsing time") On the other hand, the application hangs, if loading the page is finish, so i don't can see what will be happed at this time, when the application really calls the functions. :-/

Comment: Using a javascript debugger line-by-line takes a lot of getting used to, and frankly, I haven't gotten used to it. If your code is being fired as events, though, it still won't give you a clear picture of what's going on. Perhaps using the timeline in the dev.tools will help you with that. A less sophisticated way is to use `console.log(string)` at various points, since these will show up in the console immediately in the order in which they occur, without interrupting anything the way `alert()` does. You can also write entire objects to `console.log`, not just strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: i did not found any alternatives way than using firebug and `console.info()` or `console.warn()` to debug the code.
Thanks @ all for the comments

Comment: Try putting `debugger;` in the javascript code. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

One debugging trick I have found endlessly useful for dealing with JQuery is the insert obvious code trick.  Slap in a .hide() command on some obvious, identifiable part of the page, and see if the code ever runs.  Lets you track which code pieces are not behaving as intended, and which are simply never being used in the first place.

Comment: Why not just log something to the console?

Comment: Hadn't known about the existence of the console until I read your comment.  Still don't know how to write to it.  Suspect that it's not available on all browsers.

Comment: It's available on FF, Chrome, and IE8+. You write to it with `console.log(value);` If you want a console in other browsers, you can use [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: >Lets you track which code pieces are not behaving as intended   ---  the point is: they all are working as exacted, because there are working by using the "show menu" button. the question related the the time, when the script starts.

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd say that Michael's suggestion of the console is pretty strong.  Drop console.log() tags in various parts of the code (identifying where in the code they are), and one at the start of the script, and another at the end of the script.  Run once, and the console should tell you what order things are occurring in.  Step-through debugger would also work (and may be faster for a single run-through), but this way lets you run repeatedly with relatively little cost for each run - allowing for tweak and re-check.